# Golang interfaces and receivers - advice needed

Tags: interface, go, abstraction

I'm trying to convert my config loader class in Golang from a specific config file structure to a more general one. Originally, I defined a struct with a set of program-specific variables, for example:

```
type WatcherConfig struct {
    FileType   string
    Flag       bool
    OtherType  string
    ConfigPath string
}
```

I then defined two methods with pointer receivers:

```
func (config *WatcherConfig) LoadConfig(path string) error {}
```

and

```
func (config *WatcherConfig) Reload() error {}
```

I'm now attempting to make this more general, and the plan was to define an interface `Config` and define the `LoadConfig` and `Reload` methods on this. I could then create a `struct` with the config layout for each module that needed it, and save myself repeating a method that basically opens a file, reads JSON, and dumps it into a struct.

I've tried creating an interface and defining a method like this:

```
type Config interface {
    LoadConfig(string) error
}
func (config *Config) LoadConfig(path string) error {}
```

But that is obviously throwing errors as `Config` is not a type, it's an interface. Do I need to add a more abstract `struct` to my class? **It may be useful to know** that all configuration structs will have the `ConfigPath` field, as I use this to `Reload()` the config.

I'm fairly sure I'm going about this the wrong way, or what I'm trying to do isn't a pattern that works nicely in Go. I'd really appreciate some advice!

- Is what I'm trying to do possible in Go?
- Is it a good idea in Go?
- What would be the alternative Go-ism?

Comment: Why define a method when you can create func LoadConfig(path string) (Config, error){}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you'd use *embedding* both the interfaces and the implementations, the implementation of `Config.LoadConfig()` cannot know about the type that embeds it (e.g. `WatcherConfig`).

Best would be not to implement this as *methods* but as simple *helper* or *factory* functions.

You could do it like this:

```
func LoadConfig(path string, config interface{}) error {
    // Load implementation
    // For example you can unmarshal file content into the config variable (if pointer)
}

func ReloadConfig(config Config) error {
    // Reload implementation
    path := config.Path() // Config interface may have a Path() method
    // for example you can unmarshal file content into the config variable (if pointer)
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! I was missing the idea of the `config.Path()` method to ensure that the config object had a path string. Nice one!